# QGIS 3.16.1: Clip by mask layer not working in macOS Big SUR

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, clip, macos

I am having an issue with clipping my raster as per the vector mask layer. I did try to counter the issue with projecting both files in **same CRS**, however, still getting the same error (**ERROR 1: Cutline not of polygon type.**). I am running QGIS 3.16.1 on macOS Big Sur. Already had so many issues in running QGIS on this Mac Platform. Now this simple problem is annoying. Files are attached here.

I did try the solution provided here but to no use.
[Error in clipping raster (.bil) using vector polygon in qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225844/error-in-clipping-raster-bil-using-vector-polygon-in-qgis?rq=1)

Kind of novice with QGIS and its use on macOS.

Comment: Could not upload files here. Please suggest.

Comment: Hard to guess the problem without seeing your input polygon layer. Can you share screenshot?

Comment: How to share screenshots?

Comment: QGIS version: 3.16.1-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 3ecbe06f78
Qt version: 5.14.2
GDAL version: 3.1.2
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…

Comment: Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : '/nnnn/LandsatBands/clippedtoGHMCarea.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : '/nnnn/LandsatBands/lines.shp', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'), 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }

Comment: GDAL command:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff -cutline /nnnn/LandsatBands/lines.shp -cl lines -crop_to_cutline /nnnn/LandsatBands/clippedtoGHMCarea.tif /private/var/folders/rm/vlwh7w6j06qfhg28fvdw2j9c0000gn/T/processing_yDOvZc/4a8603cd27c4483f8fc8ce0817bcfdd9/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: Cutline not of polygon type.

Comment: Execution completed in 0.25 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/private/var/folders/rm/vlwh7w6j06qfhg28fvdw2j9c0000gn/T/processing_yDOvZc/4a8603cd27c4483f8fc8ce0817bcfdd9/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /private/var/folders/rm/vlwh7w6j06qfhg28fvdw2j9c0000gn/T/processing_yDOvZc/4a8603cd27c4483f8fc8ce0817bcfdd9/OUTPUT.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: It seems to me that your input vector layer for the mask is line not polygon. The mask has to be polygon

Comment: actually its polygon, i just named it as lines.shp

Comment: Got it resolved. Using Vector tools turned the shape file into polygon and then it worked.